# Using a folder as an sftp server on my iMac?

Tags: macos, sftp

Can I make a folder to an sftp server on my iMac that can be accessed with Cyberduck (or other software) remotely? I would like to access my iMacs files in my office from home.
How do i set it up?

As I understood, it would be better to have a dynamic ip address...

Comment: Dynamic? You mean static?

Comment: no sure what I need, I just read somewhere that I would be simpler to set up a dynamic DNS account in order to acess it through a domain

Comment: Ahh, ok. DNS and Domain stuff.

Comment: someone can help set it up?